# Find all rational zeros of the polynomials:

Tags: number-theory

Find all rational zeros of the polynomial
$$
f(x)=(4x^6)+(3x^5)-(7x^4)+(3x^2)+(27x)-63
$$
Find all rational zeros of the polynomial
$$
g(x)=(15x^3)-(2x^2)+x+14
$$

Comment: Could you please show us what you did to approach the problem?

Comment: I tried finding the real roots but neither are rational

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

To make things even simplier, when you find one rational root, let's say $x_1 = a$, the divide the polynomial with $(x-a)$. [From Polynomial Divison Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) we know that $(x-a)\mid f(x)$.

Then repeat the process again.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)$, a rational zero $\frac pq$ of the polynomial satisfies

$$q|4,p|63$$

so
$$q=1,-1,2,-2,4,-4;p=1,-1,3,-3,7,-7,9,-9,63,-63$$